# Powershell filtering/formatting when querying Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, filter, command-line-interface

Please help to format output of the command: 
     Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "West US"

Right now it shows:

```
Name                             Current Value Limit  Unit

Availability Sets                           77  322000 Count
Total Regional Cores                      4159  323000 Count
Virtual Machines                           999 32220000 Count
```

How can I pipe/filter it out so it only shows the Value for Total Regional Cores?

Selecting name shows following:

```
Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "East US" -Verbose | Select Name

Name                                               
----                                               
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.UsageName
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.UsageName
```

Thanks,
Dmitry

Comment: When add -eq , it shows error
`Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "East US" -Verbose | Select Name -eq 'Total Regional Cores'`
     `Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'eq'.`
     `At line:1 char:64 `

Comment: You should be using | Where-Object instead of Select-Object, and wrapping it in a filter statement.  Please do some research using those terms to see if they help.  As for the second issue, where you're seeing Types when selecting name, you may need to Pipe to a For Each statement, and then pull some of the properties from the UsageName objects that are being returned.

Comment: Shows nothing, tried it before.Research is a good thing, but I need an example how that would work. 
`Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "East US" -Verbose | Where-Object $_.Name -eq 'Total Regional Cores'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following command.

```
(Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "East US"|select -ExpandProperty Name).LocalizedValue
```

Here it the result.

[image]

The root reason is `Name` contain two child values:`Value` and `LocalizedValue`. If you select them directly, you will get `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.UsageName`.

Update:

> So how do I get the exact value that corresponds to Total Regonal
>   Cores

Just use following command.

```
$names= Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "East US"
foreach($name in $names) {$results = [pscustomobject]@{'name'=$name.name.LocalizedValue;'value'=$name.CurrentValue};$results}
```

[image]

Update2:

> There is a Total Regional Cores variable that holds the value of 5 in
>   your example. I want the formatting to show just this value without
>   showing anything else

```
foreach($name in $names) {$results = [pscustomobject]@{'name'=$name.name.LocalizedValue;'value'=$name.CurrentValue};$results | ?{$_.name -eq 'Total Regional Cores'}}
```

[image]

Comment: So how do I get the exact value that corresponds to Total Regonal Cores

Comment: Walter, thank you for your help, and not it is not 100% what I need. I would like  the  command to show just the number of Total Regional Cores, can this be done?

Comment: @Dmitry `Total Regional Cores` Do you mean cores that could use in one region or the cores have used?

Comment: @Dmitry If you want to get cores that have used, you could use `Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "East US"|select CurrentValue` get value and use a loop to get total cores.It is easy.

Comment: @Dmitry You could not get the value that you want directly. You need get the values every size and get the total value.

Comment: There is a Total Regional Cores variable that holds the value of 5 in your example. I want the formatting to show just this value without showing anything else